# Search with Sharepoint id in gallery

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powerapp, powerapps-canvas

I am binding my gallery with SharePoint list where I want to search data based on Id (104,103,) from my search textbox but trying below but its not working

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using `Value()` function:

```
Sort(Filter(Master,StartsWith("ID",Value(Search.Text)),Created.Email=User().Email),ID,Descending)
```

In this case, user has to enter the valid number in search textbox.

**Reference**: [Value function in Power Apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-value)

---

**Update from comments**:

If above is not working for you then use below:

```
Sort(Filter(Master,StartsWith(Text(ThisRecord.ID),Search.Text),Created.Email=User().Email),ID,Descending)
```

Comment: getting error , "powerapps invalid argument type (number) expecting a text value instead"

Comment: Use formula in updated answer.